# ADF: can't build simple Json file transformation (one field flattening)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I need a help in transforming simple json file inside Azure Data Flow. I need to flatten just one field `date_sk` in example here:

```json
    { 
      "date_sk": {"string":"2021-09-03"}
      "is_influencer": 0,
      "is_premium": -1,
      "doc_id": "234"
    }
```

Desired transformation:
`"date_sk": {"string":"2021-09-03"}`
to become
`"dateToGroupBy" : "2021-09-03"`

I create source stream, **note the strange projection Azure picks, there is no "string" field anymore**, but this is how automatic Azure transformation works for some reason:

[image]

Data preview of the same source stream node:
[image]

And here's how it suggest me to transform it in a separate "Derived Column" modifier. I played with the right part, but this is the only format (`date_sk.{}`) that does not display any error I was able to pick:

[image]

But then output `dateToGroupBy` field happens to be empty:

[image]

Any ideas on what could got wrong and how can I build the expected transformation? Thank you

Comment: In your source settings, are you using an integration dataset or an inline type? When you click on "import projection", is the schema projection updated correctly?

Comment: Source type: Dataset
No errors were shown when I made projection

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it happened to be a Microsoft bug in ADF.

ADF stumbles upon `"string"` field name as JSON field, can't handle it, though schema and data validation passes through Ok, and showing no errors.

When I replace `date_sk": {"string":"2021-09-03"}` by `date_sk": {"s1":"2021-09-03"}` or anything other than `string` everything starts working just fine
[image]

and `dateToGroupBy` is filled with date values taken from `date_sk.s1`

When I return `string` back, it shows NULL in output values.

It supposed to either show error on verification stage or handle this field naming properly.

Comment: You can also use "Import projection" to see if ADF is able to correctly sample and infer the data type properly rather than editing the script.

Comment: I did not edit the script, I edited my own source file only

Comment: Got it ... you can also edit the script behind the data flow designer to set the data type you'd like to see if the ADF inference is not correct :)